# Java Class extends @Configuration annotated Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I wrote the follow piece of code and It works but i'm not sure why.
What I wanted is to customize the jdbc configuration of spring-data-jdbc and I extended the configuration with another, but... what really happen in the IoC Container?

`JdbcConfiguration` is `@Configuration` annotated bean that instantiates a 
`JdbcCustomConversions` and i'm able to override this behavior subclassing the whole configuration and specifying ma own method, but i'm not really sure why.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomJdbcConfiguration extends JdbcConfiguration{

    @Override
    protected JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversions() {
        return new JdbcCustomConversions(Collections.singletonList(CLobToStringConverter.INSTANCE));
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    enum CLobToStringConverter implements Converter<Clob, String>{

        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String convert(Clob source) {

            try {
                return IOUtils.toString(source.getCharacterStream());
            } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```